# How do I prevent form from redirecting after submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, redirect, form-submit

I have searched the site and I've found various solutions, most of them suggesting using

```
return false;
```

Problem is that I'm using this piece of code to submit the form:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#snd").click(function() {  
        var dendar = "http://" + $("#inpt").val() + ":" + $("#pwd").val() + "secretsite.lol/something.xml";
        $("#formen").attr("action", dendar);
        $("#formen").submit();
        alert(dendar);
        return false;
    });  
});
```

The alert is just there to let me know that the form has been submitted..

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you mean how do you prevent a form from submitting?

Comment: I added a reply, but when looking at your (overly complex for the task) code, i'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Mainly due to the missing markup.

Comment: No not prevent it from submitting, I need it to submit but without redirection. When I'm clicking on the formsubmit button, I'm being redirected to the XML file I'm trying to post to. The thing is that I'm recieving the post-data, so my forms are being posted correctly, it's just the redirection I want to prevent.

Sorry for being unclear..

Comment: Um, I'm unclear on something. You can't really submit to an XML file. They don't process data. They're rather static in nature (all files can of course be edited). So how are you submitting to an XML file? Or do you mean that the page is redirecting on the server to an XML after processing the POST data?

Comment: I tried to not reveal anything detailed about my project but here I go anyway;

I'm trying to post to this link: http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml

Everything works as a charm except the redirection part!

Comment: So why doesn't an AJAXian post work here? Anyone else tried this from a browser? Should work fine. ~ Also, when you're attempting to post to a major site it doesn't hurt to share those details in the post. We're not gonna instantly know what you're planning and someone may have already done JUST WHAT YOU WANT. Food for thought.

Comment: I don't know AJAX, haven't tried that.. I've been planning this project for a year+ now, allthough I'm just starting to build the site and you're absolutely right I shouldn't have been so worried or protective

Comment: Oh well... "I don't know AJAX" ... Something you really _must_ learn, if only for your own benefit. It's just tremendous for making webpages which "zing". Best of luck! Might want to go ahead and close this question with an Answered and open a new one if you have questions about AJAX and jQuery (but search SO first, it has lots of content on that topic ~ first hand knowledge).

Comment: Right, I'll hop right on that! I just thought that something as a simple redirection question would be easier to solve with regular html or jquery :/.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well it _will be_ simple jQuery. It's built right into the lib. Glad to help where I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just using an AJAX call with POST to a data handler? That sounds like what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure but AJAX only works so long the data im sending is to the same server I'm posting from? If so then thats not an option..

Comment: Why would you be submitting cross server? It's possible to do nearly anything from a browser window with javascript, just depends on what you're attempting to do. Remember that ad services load ads from client networks. You don't think that the server retrieves all those ads and injects them into the page do you?

Comment: Anything you can do with plain HTML can be done with javascript. If you can submit now to the other server, then you can jquery.ajax post it over to that server as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for enlightening me! I learn something new everyday thanks to you guys

Comment: have you seen anything like this post (since there are so many reposts of everyone everywhere on the internet) before? http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/jquery-twitter-api-plugin.html

Answer (score 4):

You must return false within the submit() call's event handler, not the click handler.

```
$("#formen").attr("action", dendar); $("#formen").submit(
   function() { 
      return false;
   }
);
```

As pointed out by others, this will stop the form from submitting at all. What you want to do is collect the form data and submit it using an Ajax-call.

$.post( url, { var1: value1, var2: value2 etc... });

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!

Either I'm dumb and don't know how to pull this of or it's not working with my code.

This disabled my submittion entirely, I'm not getting the forms posted, and the alert isn't showing up either (I put in the alert before the return statement)..

Comment: But that's exactly what it does, it disables submission entirely. Apparently you're not asking the right question.

Comment: Sorry.. I need to my form to send information to a site, without having to redirect. When I click on the submit button, I need it to do that, post the info and just alert me that it's done that..

Comment: You should really check out the jQuery Ajax functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You can't prevent a redirect, but you can submit the form into a (possibly hidden) iframe so you don't leave the current page

Ajax would be better if the post is to the same server as the current page and you aren't posting file data

Comment: I'll try to do that, the post is made to a website that doesn't belong to me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery 1.4:

```
$("#formen").live("submit",function(e) {  
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

This will prevent the form from actually submitting. Then you're free to do whatever with the data that was supposed to be posted (use ajax, print something on the page...).

Comment: Not quite sure where to put this in, does this replace the submit codelines?

Comment: @noor add it where you want, just make sure it's called (on document ready for instance)